# AngularJS Provider wont inject into angular.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set up some constants for an Angular config through a provider, but for some reason I can't see, I keep getting the error:

> Unknown provider: myprovider

I have plenty of dependency injection throughout my project, but I can't figure out why this one will not work.

The order of the code below is the same order as in my **config.js**.

**Provider**

```
var trybConfig = angular.module('trybConfig', []);

trybConfig.provider('myprovider', function() {
this.Routes = {
    EventList: {
        Location: "/Event",
        Template: "views/eventView.html",
        Controller: "eventController"
    }
}
this.$get = function () {
    return this.Routes;
}
});
```

**Config**

```
trybConfig.config(function($routeProvider, myprovider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/Event', {
        templateUrl: 'views/eventView.html',
        controller: 'eventController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Event'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add "provider" to the name of your service prodiver, just do:

```
trybConfig.provider('my', function() {
```

And inject it:

```
trybConfig.config(function($routeProvider, myProvider) {
```

FYI - In your current state you need to inject:

```
trybConfig.config(function($routeProvider, myproviderProvider) {
```